# Unable to run unit test case for toast message in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-toastr

Hi I am developing web application in angular 5. I am using toast messages to display messages. I am using toast messages from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster. The implementation is correct and working fine. I am facing issue with writing unit test cases. Below is my implementation in component. 
I have added below line of code in component.

```
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
```

I have added below code in constructor.

```
private toasterService: ToasterService
```

I am showing toast message as below.

```
this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
```

I have added below code in HTML file.

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
```

This implementation works fine. I am writing unit test case as below.

```
describe('Component: TenantEditorComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useClass: TranslateLanguageLoader
                    }
                }),
                NgxDatatableModule,
                FormsModule,
                UiSwitchModule,
                TooltipModule.forRoot(),
                ModalModule.forRoot(),
                ToasterModule
            ],
  providers: [   ToasterService ]
        }).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TenantEditorComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        submitEl = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));
```

This is giving me error

> No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts.

I have added screenshot below.

[image]

Can someone help me to figure it out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why haven't you mocked anything ? Any particular reason ?

Comment: Hi, do i need to mock ToasterService?

Comment: Well not only that, but anything that is not used in your component. You should not have `HttpClientModule`, `TooltipModule`, `ToasterModule`, and anything that isn't included in the HTML (I imagine for instance `UiSwitchModule` being an HTML tag like `<ui-switch>`, in those cases you might leave it).

Comment: Okay So how can I write it now?

Comment: Well that's going to be very long, I recommend you start reading [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing), as it might help you way more than we ever could !

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why I am getting error in unit test case?

Comment: No idea, but if you mock your dependency, I'm 100% sure your error will go away. Seems like the error states that you didn't add `<toaster-container></toaster-container>`, or that you didn't set it as the toaster container (with something like `.init()` maybe ?)

Comment: I have added <toaster-container></toaster-container> in html. But it is giving error when running unit test case. In setup how can i initialize toaster-container?

Comment: I don't know, your library documentation might tell you that ! is this HTML in the component or somewhere else ?

Comment: It is HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

create spy for check the toasterservice.

```
     describe('Component: TenantEditorComponent', () => {
      let toasterServiceSpy: jasmine.Spy;

 const toasterSetvices = jasmine.createSpyObj('toasterSetvices', ['pop']);
     toasterServiceSpy = toasterSetvices.pop.and.returnValue(of(''));

      beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [
                    HttpClientModule,
                    RouterTestingModule,
                    TranslateModule.forRoot({
                        loader: {
                            provide: TranslateLoader,
                            useClass: TranslateLanguageLoader
                        }
                    }),
                    NgxDatatableModule,
                    FormsModule,
                    UiSwitchModule,
                    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
                    ModalModule.forRoot(),
                    ToasterModule
                ],
      providers: [    {provide: ToasterService, useValue: toasterSetvices } ]
            }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TenantEditorComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            submitEl = fixture.debugElement;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        }));

   it('Hit the Login Button', () => {
    const fixtureInstance = TestBed.createComponent<LoginComponent> 
     (LoginComponent);
    const toasterServiceInstance = 
    fixtureInstance.componentInstance.toasterService;
    fixtureInstance.detectChanges();
    component.submit();
    expect(toasterServiceSpy.calls.any()).toBe(true);

  });
```